# When input type file is included, form is not submitted

Tags: php, html

I am trying to upload an image file, it was working well one day before.

Today, when I created another input file, it went wrong. Then I tried for single input file, it was not working though.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$isSubmit=filter_input(INPUT_POST, "submit");
if(isset($isSubmit){
    echo $_POST["fileToUpload"];
}
else {
    echo "not submited";
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Now if the **form is submitted**, it goes to else part and display "**not submitted**" on browser. If I load any other page or the same page, the browser says "**localhost is waiting..**"

**Then unless I restart the server, the project fails to load.**

**But when the input type file is changed to text or other, it goes well.**

I have looked at **php.ini file** there is no problem with **max file size or file upload or post max file.**

Comment: First print what comes inside $isSubmit after submitting form.

Comment: this line  if(isset($isSubmit){  is wrong it should be  if(isset($isSubmit)){

Comment: ^^ As this error should have produced a compile fail can we assume you are running with error displays turned off. **Dont do that while developing**

Comment: use $_FILES instead of $_POST.

Comment: @MahaDev it is NULL when input type is text and "submit" when input type is text or other.

Comment: @SuchitKumar that is called error and its typing mistake lol

Comment: @RiggsFolly Array ( ) not submited is message displayed and now its localhost is waiting after refresing reloading page. :(

Comment: @RehmanMalekar i ran it, working fine. :)

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu yeah it displayed result as 
Array ( [fileToUpload] => Array ( [name] => FireShot Capture 18 - - http___localhost_63342_mfntest.jpg [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 3 [size] => 0 ) ) not submited

but again not submitted.. goes to else portion :(

Comment: size is zero, it should be size of image that is 254.48 KB ??

Comment: try this `if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){  }`

Comment: i have tried that too but it again moves to else part, i am just amazed why $_POST["submit"] is null when input type is file

Comment: If you look at your files array dump you will see `[error] => 3` that error says `The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.` And the `[tmp_name]` is blank. So the upload did not happen!!!! So its likely that something is set wrong in you `php.ini`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Do you want to hint the fiel size ?

Answer (score 0):

this is modified code, and its works on my system have a look

changes `var_dump( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]);` for  `echo $_POST["fileToUpload"];`

you cant get file from `$_POST` you need to call array `$_FILES` where all uploaded file info resides

and you cant `echo` this directly because it is a array not a string

```
<?php
$isSubmit=filter_input(INPUT_POST, "submit");
if(isset($isSubmit))
{
    var_dump( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]);
}
else {
    echo "not submited";
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: lol in if else conditional statement, else part is executed, when input type is file

Comment: tq i am gonna reset xampp

Answer (score 0):

try this:It should display the file array.

```
<?php
$isSubmit=filter_input(INPUT_POST, "submit");
if(isset($isSubmit)){//close your if block
    print_r($_FILES["fileToUpload"]);//print file data
}
else {
    echo "not submited";
}

?>
```

**if you are on window try to do this:**

open localhost (wamp/xampp), click the server icon, go to PHP, PHP Settings, and select File Uploads i.e. enable file upload.

Comment: What is changed and why? :)

Comment: @Epodax see the if block.and he should try with $_FILES not with $_POST to see data.

Comment: It's not because I don't understand, but answers with just "code" doesn't help a lot, explaining what you did and what OP did wrong often helps OP and future visitors more.

Comment: it does not goes to if block it goes to else block
please do check those with your localhost

Comment: for the first time it will go to else block i.e. at the page load time.because this is what you have written i have not changed your flow.

Comment: nope every time it goes to else part when input type is file, and thats whats happening which is logically false

Comment: why with my project it is being so?

Comment: i am using phpstorm ide and its own server, it is error with phpstorm server..
it works fine in xampp

Comment: Sorry but i have never used it so i don't know about it.

Comment: may be you can delete this question and ask another by tagging phpstorm file upload issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really not getting the `submit` button field data returned and are getting an `[fileToUpload]['error'] = 3` then the most likely thing is that your `php.ini` settings are in a mess.

These `php.ini` settings are all related to a file upload:

```
upload_max_filesize = max size of each individual file uploaded

max_file_uploads    = max number of files (each of upload_max_filesize) size 
                      allowed in a single upload

post_max_size       = max size of the POST buffer, this includes all FILES + 
                      any other fields in the form that come as well

max_input_time      = max time allowed to upload POST data

memory_limit        = can also need increasing if lots of big files are uploaded together
```

As you appear to be missing the submit button, I would say the your problem is likely to be that `post_max_size` is not large enough for the file and the other fields on the form.

Simple rule of thumb for estimating the `post_max_size` is

```
post_max_size = (upload_max_filesize * max_file_uploads) 
                 + extra space for the normal form fields
```

So check the values of all of these parameters, if you are not sure what to change post the actual values from your `php.ini` as an edit to your question  and we can make some suggestions